# How to make Ubuntu Server laptop work with external monitor only

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

An Ubuntu Server laptop supports 1280x800 resolution for its internal display, but its Intel GMA4500MHD GPU can support 1920x1080. I plugged in a VGA external monitor capable of this desired resolution, and my goal is to make this laptop use solely the external monitor, and at 1920x1080.

Now I'm being faced with two issues. First of all, running `xrandr -q` returns a `Can't open display` message. Second, meddling with `/etc/default/grub` (after having read other AU threds) has not produced any result so far. Please advise — thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 16.04.3